# Trouble checking virtual server(vps) connection with qt

Tags: qt, protocols, qnetworkreply

I want to enter in the program, ip, username and password of a virtual server(vps), and the program checks that the username and password are correct or not.

I used the following code

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("qt.network.ssl.warning=false");
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url;
    url.setHost("xx.xxx.xx.xx");
    url.setPort(3389);
    url.setUserName("administrator");
    url.setPassword("xxxx");
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    connect(manager,&QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWindow::connFinished);
}
```

output:

```
QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ProtocolUnknownError)
```

please guide me

Comment: The VPS operates TCP webserver on port 3389 with basic authentication? Your call will just do following http:// administrator:xxxx @xxxxx:3389. If you type this in your browser do you see logged-in a webpage?

Comment: No, I think, the virtual server only connects to the desktop remote (rdp)

Comment: Your request (in the above code example) is a normal TCP HTTP-Request (visiting a page).

Comment: thanks ,Which class or library should I use to check the username and password of a virtual server (rdp request)?

Comment: See my answer. It's not difficult, just open a socket connectionTCP or UDP on 3389 then disconnect once the connection was successful. If a timeout occurs, the host is offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know, if the host is online:
I would suggest you use [connectToHost](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost) from QAbstractSocket Class. The RDP-Protocol is based on TCP/UDP according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) and listens on 3389 (what you said in the comments.).

If the connection on TCP 3389 is successful, the host is online.

If you want to verify if the host is online and the authentication works you have to implement your own RDP-library such as [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), because Qt does not provide any core modules for RDP.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. <3